# There's an error in my syntax, I don't know where

Tags: mysql, syntax, syntax-error

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE customer_status(
    status_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    rank INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(status_id))
    ENGINE=innodb
    CHARSET=latin1
    COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

SEEMS THAT I CAN'T USE THE WORD RANK

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem by `rank` is a reserved word starting with 8.0.2. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R

Comment: `rank` is a reserved MySQL keyword, See other reserved keyword list here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RANK` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in MySQL. You can escape it with the backtick (`) character.

```
CREATE TABLE customer_status(
status_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
`rank` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(status_id))
ENGINE=innodb
CHARSET=latin1
COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```